# String type declaration is not comparable to string

Tags: go

I've got an alias type "LogLevel" which is a string:

```
type LogLevel string

const (
    InfoLevel  LogLevel = "info"
    DebugLevel LogLevel = "debug"
    WarnLevel  LogLevel = "warn"
    ErrorLevel LogLevel = "error"
    PanicLevel LogLevel = "panic"
    FatalLevel LogLevel = "fatal"
)
```

Now I'd like to do a switch case to check these consts against user input:

```
    switch strings.ToLower(input) {
    case "", InfoLevel:
        return zap.NewAtomicLevelAt(zap.InfoLevel)
    default:
        fmt.Errorf("Invalid log level supplied '%s'. Defaulting to info loglevel", input)
        return zap.NewAtomicLevelAt(zap.InfoLevel)
    }
```

This doesn't work because apparently the types are incompatible?

> invalid case InfoLevel in switch on strings.ToLower(input) (mismatched
>   types LogLevel and string)

How can I use the defined consts in the cases?

Comment: Edited the title, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the operands in an [comparison](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) must be [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the other.  The type `string` is not assignable to `LogLevel` and vice versa.  To get comparable values, [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the `string` to a `LogLevel`:

```
switch LogLevel(strings.ToLower(input)) {
```

Comment: Even when the input can be something else than the values defined in LogLevel? That's what I am testing in the switch case at all

Comment: @kentor The constants defined by the application do not limit the possible values for a `LogLevel`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I'll accept the answer once the minimum 15mins passed.

Answer (score 3):

`type LogLevel string` is a type definition.

`type LogLevel = string` is a type alias.

It looks like you want the latter and not the former.

Comment: Though that would solve the immediate problem, it seems unlikely this is the correct solution; this appears to be a string-type enumeration, for which a type definition would be more correct than an alias.